# Formatting a Hexadecimal number with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Is it possible to print a number as a hex string in thymeleaf?

I have a number (ex: 16711680) and I want to print it as 0xFF0000 on a page.

I can do this before sending the value to the context via `String.format("0x%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));`. I'd much rather have the view layer format the value. How the number is displayed should be it's concern.

I looked over all the #{numbers} formatters thymeleaf provides. Nothing seems to provide this type of formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `T` [Type Operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-types) to call static methods on a class. So you can just call `String.format()` as you usually would. eg.

```
${T(java.lang.String).format('0x%06X', intColor)}
```

The only slight limitation here is you can't perform the bitwise and from within Thymeleaf. You'll either need to do this before you add it to the model, or maybe look at [Integer.toHexString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-) which will allow you to format your number as if it were unsigned:

```
'0x'+${T(java.lang.Integer).toHexString(intColor).toUpperCase()}
```

This second approach requires some additional work to get the leading `0x` and to uppercase the characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OGNL and not Spring-EL (as in Andrew's answer) the syntax to call static methods is `@class@method`. E.g.: `${@java.lang.Integer@toHexString(someNumber)}`